# How to use Win32 API's DATETIMEPICKER

Tags: winapi, datetimepicker

I am studying Win32 API using plain C. While trying to implement some code that queries a DB, I faced a problem with retrieving start and end dates of the query using `datetimepicker`.

I have two datetimepickers.

When hitting the query button, two dates must be retrieved and sent to a DB server over a query. In order to handle this, I have come up with two ideas.

Processing it under case WM_NOTIFY. Below is my code to process the message.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
  HWND picker = (HWND) lpnmhdr->hwndFrom;
  if(lpnmhdr->code == DTN_DATETIMECHANGE){
    if(picker == GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_START_DATE)){
      HWND DTP_start = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_START_DATE);
      DWORD dwTextLength_S = GetWindowTextLength(DTP_start);
      char s_date[dwTextLength_S + 1];
      GetWindowText(DTP_start, s_date, dwTextLength_S + 1);
    } else if(picker == GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_END_DATE)){
      HWND DTP_end = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_END_DATE);
      DWORD dwTextLength_E = GetWindowTextLength(DTP_start);
      char e_date[dwTextLength_E + 1];
      GetWindowText(DTP_end, e_date, dwTextLength_E + 1);
    } 
...
```

Processing it under case WM_COMMAND. Below is my code to process the message.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
  switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
    case ID_DDAN_TAB_INT_Q_BTN: // this is the query button
    {
      HWND DTP_start = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_START_DATE);
      HWND DTP_end = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ID_DDAN_TAB_END_DATE);
      DWORD dwTextLength_S = GetWindowTextLength(DTP_start);
      DWORD dwTextLength_E = GetWindowTextLength(DTP_end);
      char s_date[dwTextLength_S + 1];
      char e_date[dwTextLength_E + 1];
      GetWindowText(DTP_start, s_date, dwTextLength_S + 1);
      GetWindowText(DTP_end, e_date, dwTextLength_E + 1);
      ...
```

While handling both messages, I am not able to retrieve the values in the `datetimepicker`.

Would someone please give me an explanation or example how to handle the `DATETIMEPICKER` event?

Comment: Pretty unclear why you need "events" or why you are tinkering with strings.  Use DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME to retrieve the selected dates.  And add a check to verify that a valid range was selected.

Comment: @HansPassant it works. thank you very much for your information.